# In Orchard - How can I create one element in my module

Tags: orchardcms

How can I create my own elements in Orchard Create new page window

Image URL :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0LukXeHz5VdREtvd19GSHZ1Tm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also have w look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981090/how-to-create-layout-elements-in-orchard-1-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered here: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/643710

## Copied from CodePlex:

You can create your own elements by implementing classes that derive from the Element class in the Orchard.Layouts.Framework.Elements namespace. You also need to implement an element driver for your element (even if it contains no members, the TypedElementHarvester relies on this to discover elements).

Checkout the Html element for a good example.

Here's an example of a custom element:

```
using Orchard.Layouts.Framework.Elements;

public class MyElement : Element {
    public override LocalizedString DisplayText {
        get { return T("My Custom Element"); }
    }

    public int SomeCustomProperty {
       get { return this.Retrieve(x => x.SomeCustomProperty); }
       set { this.Store(x => x.SomeCustomProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And here is its driver:

```
using Orchard.Layouts.Framework.Drivers;

public class MyElementDriver : ElementDriver<MyElement> {
  // Optionally override members like BuildEditor and UpdateEditor similar to creating content part drivers.
}
```

For complete examples, checkout the source code in the Orchard.Layouts module, specifically the Elements and Drivers folders. 
Let me know if you have any further questions.